# Applying PCA to 2 dimentional feature arrays

Tags: python, r, pca

I am working with a database where for each element (individual sample) of the database I have a 150x160 matrix of features. The columns of the matrix represent spatial dimantion and the rows represent frequency. So for each element, I have data of the intensity at different points of the sample and for different frequencies. I want to apply a PCA to reduce the dimentionality of the dataset and, additionally, maximize the variability of the dataset before applying machine learning algorithms. But I don't know how to apply PCA in this case, as I normally use it for 1 dimentional data arrays. All help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For dimensionality reduction of a 2D matrix using PCA, you could do the following using Singular Value Decomposition:

```
# Let X be the feature matrix 
U,S,VT = np.linalg.svd(X)
T = X@VT.T
```

To take the first *k* features of the PCA, we simply do

```
T = X@VT.T[:,0:k]
```